# ModelBuilder tool not working but standalone works

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a Model built that iterates through a GDB of rasters. The first tool is to Times the raster by 1000 to bring, then convert it to an interger for Euclidean Allocation. But the Times tool doesn't return the proper values, I tried with Raster Calculator as well and it created the same results. So, if I'm expecting `high = 4560000` and `low= 122.102` it actually returns `-3.9999999` for both high and low values of the raster.

But when I use the standalone Times or Raster Calculator I get the results I need.

What is the difference between the tool in ModelBuilder vs. standalone?

Comment: What does a test model with just this first (Times) part of your model look like?  What parameter values did you provide to the Times tool?

Comment: That's what I've done is created a submodel that just iterates through the GDB and runs the Times tool. So far it works with my input raster and my constant value as 1000000 in order to maintain the significant digits for when I revert back to a float.

Comment: What does that sub model look like as a picture?  Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.